# JavaScript driven apps that don't use hyperlinks for most actions. Isn't is super annoying?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, ajax

I see a glaring issue in many popular implementations of the modern web app -- not using hyperlinks for all actions.

Steam is definitely the worst offender I have experienced so far. If you have ever used their community portals via browser you will notice that you can rarely ever right click on an action and open it in a new tab. Google also does this in most of its apps as well. New tabbing actions is what I am all about. In fact, it's the main, if not only reason why I can honestly argue why web apps can be better than native apps. But no, instead of using hyperlinks for each actions, they use a generic html tag like a span or a div and then listen for click events on them, which is fine if you click, but when you right click the browser has no idea that it is actually linking to an specific url or action.

Sorry to ramble on so much. **But seriously, isn't it a terrible UX practice to build Javascript heavy, Single Page apps in this manner?** Being able to multitask is imo the best part of the web. Try doing that using Native apps.

*End Rant

Comment: Hope you have taken this out of your system, but thissite  is for UX questions.  Maybe try the chat

Comment: So not being able to right-click and open links in a new tab when using major apps such as Steam and Google isn't a UX concern? I thought about posting in the development section but it's not a technical topic. As you can see, I wasn't able to post any code because it doesn't make sense to.

Comment: You just need to reword your rant into a question

Comment: My bad. I thought this was also a discussion format. I'll anticipate the deletion.

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it is not seeking a solution to a specific concept of concern in usability.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree. Not being able to open a link in a new tab/window is a bad UX practice. In addition, not using URLs prevents users from bookmarking the page. It also prevents users from being able to navigate by adjusting the URL (for example, going back to a root path). Now with JavaScript frameworks like Backbone, Ember, and Angular, it's really easy to support URL based routing in your JavaScript applications. In summary, use URLs to represent resources and actions like they were designed to do.